# Why my program runs through the if loops as if it didn't check the if loops == TRUE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

The program should add all multiples of 3 and 5, up to the value passed. But instead it seems to add every number regardless of the multiple. It should return 23, but instead returns 45. Why?

```
def solution(number=10):
    i = 0
    c = 0
    while i < number:
        if number % 3 == 0:
            c += i
        elif number % 5 == 0:
            c += i
        i += 1

    return c
```

Comment: `if number % 3` should be `if i % 3`? As it is, your conditions don't involve the index `i`, which is a bit odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases adding a debug statement often helps to identify the problem:

```
def solution(number=10):
    i = 0
    c = 0
    while i < number:
        if number % 3 == 0:
            c += i
        elif number % 5 == 0:
            c += i
        print('i={}, c={}, number={}, number%3={}, number%5={}'.format(i, c, number, number%3, number%5))
        i += 1

    return c

solution()
```

and this prints:

```
i=0, c=0, number=10, number%3=1, number%5=0
i=1, c=1, number=10, number%3=1, number%5=0
i=2, c=3, number=10, number%3=1, number%5=0
i=3, c=6, number=10, number%3=1, number%5=0
i=4, c=10, number=10, number%3=1, number%5=0
i=5, c=15, number=10, number%3=1, number%5=0
i=6, c=21, number=10, number%3=1, number%5=0
i=7, c=28, number=10, number%3=1, number%5=0
i=8, c=36, number=10, number%3=1, number%5=0
i=9, c=45, number=10, number%3=1, number%5=0
```

Note that for simple cases a `print` (if you just want to inspect variables `print(locals())` is very handy!) is sufficient but there are also other debugging tools like [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

The reason why this is failing is that you compared the modulo of `number` instead of `i`. `number=10` so `number%5==0` is always `True`. See also the comment of @JohnColeman.

Change it to `i % ... == 0`:

```
def solution(number=10):
    i = 0
    c = 0
    while i < number:
        if i % 3 == 0:
            c += i
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            c += i
        print('i={}, c={}, number={}, i%3={}, i%5={}'.format(i, c, number, i%3, i%5))
        i += 1

    return c

solution()
```

which prints:

```
i=0, c=0, number=10, i%3=0, i%5=0
i=1, c=0, number=10, i%3=1, i%5=1
i=2, c=0, number=10, i%3=2, i%5=2
i=3, c=3, number=10, i%3=0, i%5=3
i=4, c=3, number=10, i%3=1, i%5=4
i=5, c=8, number=10, i%3=2, i%5=0
i=6, c=14, number=10, i%3=0, i%5=1
i=7, c=14, number=10, i%3=1, i%5=2
i=8, c=14, number=10, i%3=2, i%5=3
i=9, c=23, number=10, i%3=0, i%5=4
```

and returns 23.